# Using innerText without async in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i was creating a certain code of puppeteer ,and i wanted to know if there's a way to get innertext or innerHtml or textcontent while using puppeteer without an async function.

Comment: No, Puppeteer doesn't have a synchronous API. Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `await` to use an async function in a synchron way.
Please note that this does not only apply to puppeteer, but javascript in general.

```js
var text = await page.evaluate(() =>
   document.querySelector('#example').innerHTML
);
```

Comment: This is still async, just different syntax.